# Is it impossible to reduce the arguments needed for Child Class compared to its Parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, arguments, parent-child

This is my first post here and I'm new to python and excited to learn. I hope my post here is clear enough for everyone.

Is there anyone that knows if it's possible to reduce the arguments needed for a child class from its parents' inheritance?

Here's the example:

```
# this is a code to estimate any polygon's perimeter (parent)
# the second one is code to estimate a square's area (child)

    class RegularPolygon:
    `def __init__(self, 
                 no_of_sides=0, 
                 side_length=0):`
        `self.no_of_sides = no_of_sides`
        `self.side_length = side_length`
        
    `def perimeter(self):`
        `perimeter =  self.no_of_sides * self.side_length`
        `return perimeter`

    `class Square(RegularPolygon):`
        `def __init__(self, 
                 no_of_sides=4, 
                 side_length=0):`
            `super().__init__(no_of_sides, side_length)`   
        
        `def area(self):`
            `area = self.side_length ** 2`
            `return area`
```

I'm trying call child class and to estimate square. Because it's a square it always has 4 sides, so `no_of_sides` = will always 4. I'm thinking of making it automatic hence I can call class Square with just one arguments.

Here's what i expect from them:

```
    `item = Square(5)`
    `item.area()`
>>> 20
    `item.perimeter()`
>>>20
```

I tried giving basic value to their arguments (parent, child, parent&child) but still always got wrong result.
Is there anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each class's constructor can have whatever signature you want; just make sure that the child calls the parent with the appropriate arguments.

```
class RegularPolygon:
    def __init__(self, no_of_sides, side_length):
        self.no_of_sides = no_of_sides
        self.side_length = side_length
    
    def perimeter(self):
        return self.no_of_sides * self.side_length


class Square(RegularPolygon):
    def __init__(self, side_length):
        RegularPolygon.__init__(self, 4, side_length)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using this and it works all well! Thank you. What's the key here btw? Is it the line RegularPolygon.__init__(self, 4, side_length) under the class child? Without asking the number of sides in line 2, I could just attach the constructor needed from its parent's. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, `RegularPolygon.__init__()` is the parent class's constructor.  You could use `super().__init__` instead but IMO when you need to pass specific args to a specific constructor it's less confusing to just specify the one you mean (and it's much easier to handle multiple inheritance that way if that situation ever comes up).

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is probably better to remove those `__init__` arguments altogether.

Your `Square` class just needs to take in the arguments it needs (`side_length`), and not let users of the class override the `no_of_sides` of 4.

```py
class Square(RegularPolygon):
   def __init__(self, side_length):
      super().__init__(no_of_sides=4, side_length=side_length)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that suggestion just now and I got this instead. 

File "<ipython-input-1-2214e4de7ef7>", line 16
    super().__init__(no_of_sides=4, side_length)
                                   ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument.

I've been trying a combination of something similar but often ended up with that error before too.

Comment: @RG182 You need to do `(no_of_sides=4, side_length=side_length)`. In your comment you have a positional argument (`side_length`) which follows a keyword (`no_of_sides=4`)